# CSS consider animation with changing size when aligning text

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a small website to learn a bit about HTML, CSS and maybe some PHP and JS later on.

On it I have styled `<strong>` to grow and shrink over time, which I know is questionable design at best.
here's the code:

```
strong {    
    animation: grow .7s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275) infinite alternate;
    color: red;
    text-shadow: 0 0 3px black;
    size: 120%;
}

@keyframes grow {
    0% {
        font-size: 80%;
    }
    80%,
    100% {
        font-size: 120%;
        text-shadow: 0 0 6px black;
    }
}
```

Problem is that the whole paragraph constantly moves because of 1 word growing and shrinking.
Is there a way to give it enough space so the word grows but the paragraph stays static?

I've tried giving it a margin but then it grows with it.

**EDIT:**
alright maybe my question isn't clear, I'll try to rephrase it maybe it'll help.

So say I have a CSS animation that changes size.
The size is always somewhere between `80%` and `120%`.
e.g.:

```
@keyframes animation {
   from {
      font-size: 80%;
   }
   to {
      font-size:100%;
   }
}
```

Is there a way to tell CSS to take the biggest size in the animation (`120%`), and format the site as if `font-size` was always `120%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good on you for taking the time to tinker!  I think that's the best way to learn.  The issue you're running into here is that the browser is making space for the larger and smaller word inside the `<strong>` tag; that is, changing the `font-size` changes how much space the browser needs to make for text.  You want to animate a property that doesn't change how much space the browser needs to make, and for this case I think the best choice would be `transform: scale(X, Y)`.

Although the `transform` property can change the *visual* appearance of an element, it doesn't change how much space the browser makes for it next to other elements, so it's a good choice for this kind of effect.  One tricky thing here is that you cannot apply `transform` to a `display: inline` kind of element (which `strong` is by default), so you also have to change that property as well.  It's simple though (demo below).

Good luck with your learning—I hope the web dev bug bites you as hard as it bit me!

```css
@keyframes grow {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
  }
  80%, 100% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  }
}

p {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

strong {
  animation: grow .7s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275) infinite alternate;
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum, ipso facto.  The quick brown fox <strong>jumped</strong> over the lazy red dog.  All work and no play make Jack a dull boy.</p>
```